Electrostatic Self-energies of Non-uniformly charged bodies

Consider the figure given above. A semicircular ring of radius $R$ and mass m carries non uniform linear charge density $λ=λ_o\sin\theta$. A rod of mass $m$, length $2R$ and uniform linear charge $λ_o$ is placed along diameter of semicircular ring. Assume gravity free space and ignore gravitation interaction between ring and rod.
We have to find the potential energy of 'rod and semicircular ring' system
The standard way might be to calculate the force between the two objects and integrating to get the energy.
My approach was to find the interaction energy of the system, and then add the respective self energies. I found the interaction energy (I think one gets a double integral to deal with the two parameters), but I cannot figure out how to proceed with the calculation of the self energies.
Looking at this question, I realized that I did not know how to calculate the self energies of any kind of charge distribution (other than a uniformly charged spherical body, like a solid sphere or a shell combination).
So my question is, how do we proceed with the calculation of self energies of such charge distribution.

See eqn. 8.27 here. The same formula applies to self-energy or interaction energy. You are just summing over all pairs of charges.

Thanks @Ghoster for the reference. But I am new to this concept, and I only know the derivations of spherically symmetric structures (where its easy to apply that formula), but in other cases, I'm quite confused. So if you could just show me how its done for a uniformly charged rod, I might try an do the other thing myself.

For the rod you’d have the integral $\iint\frac{dx_1dx_2}{|x_1-x_2|}$ up to multiplicative constants. But, actually, the self-energy of a one-dimensional charged object is infinite because such integrals diverge. So you are probably not supposed to think about the self-energies.

Oh, so I think I will go ahead via the force method only then. Thanks!
